# State is null when trying to access it in the parent component, but able to pass it down to child component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io, chat

**EDIT:** Simplified the code a bit by using two separate states. Adding the *channel* state to the dependency array of useEffect() does not remove the error but does make the application run in a strange manner: If I try to send messages, I see multiple messages.

**EDIT 2:** If I use the useRef() hook to store the state, my application works albeit in a strange manner again: the state is *one step slower* than the actual user input.

I'm trying to build a simple chat application using React.js and Socket.IO where a single user can communicate with multiple users. I have an endpoint from where I fetch all my channel data and store it in a state but I'm not able to access the state (returns null) even if the state is being passed down to a different component as props and that is being rendered correctly the first time. When I click on a channel to select it, the channel list is again reset to null and I get this error:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'forEach')

I'm trying to implement this by following the tutorial from [here](https://www.fullstacklabs.co/blog/chat-application-react-express-socket-io). It's outdated, so I'm implementing a newer version of it. But even then, if I use the component class defined in the author's [github](https://github.com/davidzas/react-chat/blob/master/src/chat/Chat.js), it seems to work just fine. I have not worked with component classes before, so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Main component: Chat.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ChannelList from './ChannelList';
import './chat.css';
import MessagePanel from './MessagePanel';
import { io }  from "socket.io-client";

const SERVER = "http://localhost:8080";

let socket;

function Chat() {

  const [channel, setChannel] = useState(null)
  const [channels, setChannels] = useState(null) //the state where the channels are loaded
  const channelsRef = useRef() //edit 2

  useEffect(() => {
    loadChannels() //the function which loads the channels into the state
    configureSocket()
  }, []) //adding channel to the dependency array results in strange behavior.

  const configureSocket = () => {
    socket = io(SERVER)
    socket.on('connection', () => {
      if(channel) {
        handleChannelSelect(channel.id)
      }
    });

    socket.on('channel', channel => {
      console.log('channel details', channel); //returns the correct channel clicked on
      //let temp_channels = channels; //edit 2
      let temp_channels = channelsRef.current; //edit 2
      console.log('channels inside onchannel', temp_channels); //returns null, does not return null if useRef() is used
      temp_channels.forEach(c => { //I get the above mentioned error at this line, after edit 2 I don't get any error
        if(c.id === channel.id) {
          c.participants = channel.participants
        }
      })
      //setChannels(channels); edit 2
      channelsRef.current = temp_channels // edit 2
    })

    socket.on('message', message => {
      // let temp_channels = channels
      let temp_channels = channelsRef.current //edit 2
      temp_channels.forEach(c => {
        if (c.id === message.channel_id) {
          if (!c.messages) {
            c.messages = [message];
          } else {
            c.messages.push(message);
          }
        }
      })
      // setChannels(channels) edit 2
      channelsRef.current = temp_channels // edit 2
    })
  }

  const handleSendMessage = (channel_id, text) => {
    socket.emit('send-message', { channel_id, text, senderName: socket.id, id: Date.now()})
  }

  const handleChannelSelect = (id) => {
    const channel = channels.find(c => {
      return c.id === id;
    });
    setChannel(channel);
    socket.emit('channel-join', id, ack => {});
  }

  const loadChannels = async () => {
    await fetch('http://localhost:8080/getChannels')
      .then(async response => {
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log('data inside loadchannels', data.channels);
        setChannels(data.channels); //this sets the channels and passes it down to the child component "ChannelList"
        channelsRef.current = data.channels //if setChannels is not used before this, it doesn't work
      })
      console.log('after fetching channels inside loadchannels', channel, channels); //both channel and channels state are null
  }

  return (
    <div className="chat-app">
      <ChannelList channels={channels} onSelectChannel={handleChannelSelect}></ChannelList>
      <MessagePanel onSendMessage={handleSendMessage} channel={channel}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Chat;
```

ChannelList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Channel from './Channel';

function ChannelList(props) {
  const handleClick = (id) => {
    props.onSelectChannel(id);
  }

  console.log('inside channellist component', props.channels); //returns the set of channels received from props

  let list = <div className="no-content-message">There are no channels to show</div>;
  if (props.channels && props.channels.map) {
    list = props.channels.map(c =>
      <Channel
        key={c.id}
        id={c.id}
        name={c.name}
        participants={c.participants}
        onClick={handleClick}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className='channel-list'>
      {list}
    </div>
  );

}

export default ChannelList;
```

Backend index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
http = require('http');
const cors = require('cors');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');

app.use(cors());

const server = http.createServer(app);

const STATIC_CHANNELS = [
  {
    name: 'Global chat',
    participants: 0,
    id: 1,
    sockets: []
  },
  {
    name: 'Funny',
    participants: 0,
    id: 2,
    sockets: []
  },
  {
    name: 'Test',
    participants: 0,
    id: 3,
    sockets: []
  },
];

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  },
});

server.listen(8080, () =>
  console.log('Server is running on port 8080')
);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(`User connected ${socket.id}`);

  socket.emit('connected', socket.id);

  socket.on('channel-join', id => {
    console.log('channel join', id);
    STATIC_CHANNELS.forEach(c => {
      if (c.id === id) {
        if (c.sockets.indexOf(socket.id) == (-1)) {
          c.sockets.push(socket.id);
          c.participants++;
          io.emit('channel', c);
        }
      } else {
        let index = c.sockets.indexOf(socket.id);
        if (index != (-1)) {
          c.sockets.splice(index, 1);
          c.participants--;
          io.emit('channel', c);
        }
      }
    });
    return id;
  })

  socket.on('send-message', message => {
    io.emit('message', message);
  })

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    STATIC_CHANNELS.forEach(c => {
      let index = c.sockets.indexOf(socket.id);
      if(index != (-1)) {
        c.sockets.splice(index, 1);
        c.participants--;
        io.emit('channel', c);
      }
    })
  })
});

app.get('/getChannels', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    channels: STATIC_CHANNELS
  })
})
```

Comment: The useState hook is async and will not update the value until the next render of your page. The value is being updated, but not before your code reaches and runs the console.log() where you are attempting to check the value. You can use a useEffect hook to process changes to the state of the channel and channels variables based on when they change.

Comment: I tried doing that. But I am confused on what I should put in the dependency array of the useEffect hook.

Comment: Use either [state.channel] or [state.channels]. You can use as many useEffects as you need to correctly process all possible changes. I'd also suggest breaking your channel and channels objects into their own states by using two useState hooks, as this will simplify things for you a bit.

Comment: You can use `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` that will help you with which dependencies should be set to the dependency array hooks (including `useEffect` hook)

Comment: Simplified the code by breaking down the states. Now, if I put channels in the dependency array, it's causing an infinite rerender as loadChannels changes channels. Putting channel in the dependency array causes strange behavior as mentioned in the edit. I also have the `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` and if I put the dependencies which it suggests to me, I still get an infinite re-render.